# Lex/Flex Scanner Isn't Scanning and I Have No Idea Why

Tags: c, flex-lexer, lex

I have written a simple lex scanner in the file `myscanner.l`, where testlex.h is just a bunch of #defines as integers (MATCH_0 == 0, etc)

```
%{
#include "testlex.h"
%}

%%

"dinky"         return MATCH_0;
"pinky"         return MATCH_1;
"stinky"        return MATCH_2;
[ \t\n]         ;
.               printf("unexpected character\n");

%%

int yywrap(void)
{
    return 1;
}
```

After using lex to create the lex.yy.c file, I implement the code using this C file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "myscanner.h"

extern int yylex();
extern int yylineno;
extern char* yytext;

int main(void)
{
    int l = yylex();
    while (l)
    {
        printf("%d\n", l);
        l = yylex();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I pass it this input stream: `dinky pinky stinky stinky pinky dinky`, there is absolutely no output. The output I am expecting looks like this:

```
0
1
2
2
1
0
```

Not even "unexpected character". I know my stack is set up right because I've compiled others' examples and they all scan correctly, but for some inconceivable reason my code _will_not_scan_!

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why your code does not print anything is that your first input happens to be `"dinky"`, which returns `MATCH_0`. According to your expected output, `MATCH_0` is zero. Therefore, the code will exit right away, before entering the loop even once.

Re-defining `MATCH_0` to 1, `MATCH_1` to 2, and so on will fix this problem.

Comment: Thanks! Wow, I need to get some sleep!

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your expected output, what you see is the simple result of defining `"dinky"` -> `MATCH_0` as `0`.

The first value of `l` now becomes `0`, after having scanned `dinky`. So `while(l)` is `while(0)` and the block is not even executed once. Subsequently your main immediately returns `0`.

So don't define any tokens as `0`, and then write:

```
int main(void)
{
    int token;
    while (token = yylex())
    {
        printf("%d\n", token);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

To be honest I'm surprised you did not find this yourself. Simply trying other input would immediately have giving a clue. And, it should be easy to find that `yylex()` returns `0` at EOF.

BTW, I think it's better to not use `l` as variable name as it's almost the same as `1`.

Comment: @i-live-in-a-storm-drain Yeah go ahead, good luck with making your code confusing.